Why does my integrator slowly saturate to negative rail in the following configuration?
So I have the following basic integrator circuit:

The input signal is a 100mVp-p square wave of 50k frequency. In this case I get a stable triangle wave output.

However, when I make the amplitude 500mVp-p keeping everything else same the level around which output oscillates gradually decreases and settles near negative rail. What is the reason for this? I understand that putting a feedback should fix this, but my issue is, I am never letting the cap charge in one direction, so there should be no reason for it to hit the rails.


Regarding why one waveform saturates in the simulation and another doesn't could you post the waveform code, perhaps there is an error in one.

Is the square wave source exactly a 50% duty cycle? The definition of a square wave in SPICE code is a bit tricky since the rise & fall times need to be considered. Also, take a look at the current waveform on the output of the opamp. You may be asking for to much current at higher voltage drive due to the values of R & C which may cause an offset in the output voltage (|max| and |min| values not the same). Kinder values would be 200 ohms and 10nF.

In a perfectly ideal case, it would.
But the simulator you're using appears to model the op-amp as having nonzero input offset and input bias currents. This means that, as far as the op amp is concerned, your input signal may have a small DC bias, which it dutifully integrates over time to produce the drift you see.
This is why real integrators usually include a zeroing resistor across the capacitor, to bleed off this sort of slow output drift. Even using an auto-zero op amp (aka chopper amplifier) won't fully prevent this, though it may allow you to use a larger resistance, thus keeping your integrator closer to an ideal integrator.

but in this case it should have saturated in the 100mV condition as well right? But it doesn't.

@needbrainscratched Your 500 mV condition was simulated for much longer, giving time for the output to saturate. I suspect the 100 mV one will also saturate (perhaps slower, depending on op-amp characteristics) if you give it enough time.

More likely an effect of the bias currents, moreso than input offset voltage.


Why does my integrator slowly saturate to negative rail in the following configuration?

No op-amp is perfect. All op-amps have some offset voltage and bias current. These will eventually saturate an integrator unless there is a resistor in parallel with the capacitor.

Like Hearth and Math said, the opamp has bias current that gets integrated in the long term. Putting a high value resistor across the cap will help. Another trick is to put a resistor in series with the non-inverting input as a means of compensation. Not a great solution, but it helps. A complex way to deal with this problem is to use another op-amp and "servo" out the error with a large time constant - much larger than you integration period.

You said it yourself. It is an integrator. It means that a DC signal in input implies a slope in output, the closer to 0V is the input, the slower the slope of the output signal. It means that you may have a negative DC voltage very close to 0. This is where you face the realities of ideal integrator and practical integrator. Anyways, you can give a glance at this link to have an idea about how you could tackle/limit this issue : https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/analog-integrated-circuits/op-amp-integrator/practical-integrator/
They use a resistor in parallel with the integrating capacitor. It allows the capacitor to not keep its charge when there is not supposed to be any. I let you find the value of this resistor in parallel in the same link.
